# Why does Map with a pointer to template functor as value_type not work?

Tags: c++, templates, functor, stdmap

Visual studio borks when I try to create a std::map with the value type being a pointer to template-functor. Am I doing something illegal here ?

```
// Functor prototype
template< class T, class evenT>
class FunctionHandler {};

// std::Map definition
template <class T, class evenT>
map<int, FunctionHandler<T, evenT>* > lookup;
```

Can someone please tell me if this is an error (and why is this wrong) or is it just Visual studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have a "variable template".  It doesn't make any sense.

You need to create a variable with a specific type (i.e. specific values for `T` and `evenT`), or do something like:

```
template <class T, class evenT>
class SomeClass
{
    map<int, FunctionHandler<T, evenT>* > lookup;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood entirely the term "variable template". When T and evenT are defined, FunctionHandler* would represent a concrete type..so it should work then ?

Comment: "variable template" like "function template" or "class template".  It's not a valid concept in C++, not least because it would serve no useful purpose!  If `T` and `evenT` are defined types, then you should be able to safely remove the `template <...>` before the definition of `lookup`, and everything should compile.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. Makes more sense now. Well, I am stuck with this problem, and I don't know a good way to handle this. Maybe, you can suggest a better way to deal with this. Map in this case represents a <eventType, EventListener::(*functionHandler)>. This obviously is not working for the reason you mentioned. The way I made it work for now is: Map:: <eventType, FunctionBase*> and FunctionHandler<T,EvenT> inherits from FunctionBase with a virtual function. But this introduces an unnecessary virtual entry. So, what would be a good way to deal with this situation ?

Comment: @brainydexter: What situation? You tried to make a "variable template" which is something that does not exist. Why did you think you needed to use one of these?

Comment: I am trying to implement an eventManager in a game, where anyone can publish events and only those who subscribe to events would receive them. This map here keeps a track of the eventType and the function that each listener registers with eventManager, to handle that specific event

Comment: @brainydexter: So are you trying to map a handler to a *type*?  What does the `int` have to do with it?  May I suggest that you start a new question, where you try to describe your *goal*.